# Disable URL encoding of the query string in qtkwebit

Tags: qtwebkit

I'm using qtwebkit to build a DOM-XSS scanner. By default qtwebkit is automatically URL encoding/escaping the query part of the URL. Javascript gets the URL encoded.

For example, when you visit the URL

> http://test.com/?param=value<b>value</b>&a=b

**location.href** will contain the value

> http://test.com/?param=value%3Cb%3Evalue%3C/b%3E&a=b

This is a big problem for me in detecting DOM-XSS vulnerabilities because I don't know if the browser did the encoding or the webpage did it. I'm trying to disable this functionality but I'm lost in the qtwebkit source code.

Anybody can help me by telling me where exactly in the code (in what file) the URL encoding takes place so I can modify the source code and recompile it?

I've been browsing the source code for 3 days now and I didn't make any progress.

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encounter your problem on Qt5,but Qt4 don't has this problem.
I modified Qt source code "qurlrecode.cpp" 's static function recode
This solved my problem, but I think it is best to modify webkit source code on KURL, but I failed to build webkit on my machine successfully after wasting one whole day.

Answer (score 0):

QURL.setEncodedUrl(const QByteArray & encodedUrl) can solve it

via..http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qurl.html#setEncodedUrl

Comment: With example and explanation, this answer can be a great one